# I would like to stop my countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first post here. I'm not very familiar with JS and can't get the hang of it yet. I have been trying all sorts of code for days to try to stop my countdown timer before it times out (it's not my code) but to no avail so have given up "guessing" and will ask the experts. Thanks in Advance.

```
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">STOP</button><p>

<script> 
function countDown(frm)
{ 
var start=frm.v1.value; 
var now=new Date(); 
var end=new Date(frm.yr.value,frm.mth.value-    1,frm.day.value,frm.hrs.value,frm.min.value); 
var diff = (end - now)/1000; 
var step=(start-frm.v2.value)/diff; 
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=start; 
var myint=setInterval(function(){start=start-step;     document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=start.toFixed(2); 
if(start<frm.v2.value){document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Ended";     clearInterval(myint)}},1000);
}


function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myint);
}
</script>
```

I have tried your updates (see below) however the counter will no longer start. I may have misunderstood your reply.

```
var myint; 
function countDown(frm) 
{ 
var start=frm.v1.value; 
var now=new Date(); 
var end=new Date(frm.yr.value,frm.mth.value-    1,frm.day.value,frm.hrs.value,frm.min.value); 
var diff = (end - now)/1000; 
var step=(start-frm.v2.value)/diff; 
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=start; 

}
{
myint=setInterval(function(){start=start-step;     document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=start.toFixed(2); 
if(start<frm.v2.value)    {document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Ended";clearInterval(myint)}},1000); 
}

function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myint);
}
```

Your a "Whiz" thank you very much. After reading you reply for the hundredth time I could see that I definitely misunderstood your reply. It now works fine. I am a learner.

Answer (score 4):

`myStopFunction` does not know what `myint` is because `myint` is local to `countDown`. An easy solution would be to make `myint` global by placing it outside of `countDown`.

```
var myint;
function countDown(frm)
{ 
 ...
 myint=setInterval(... //note the lack of var here
 ...
}

function myStopFunction()
{
 clearInterval(myint);
}
```

Comment: var myint; 
function countDown(frm) 
{ 
var start=frm.v1.value; 
var now=new Date(); 
var end=new Date(frm.yr.value,frm.mth.value-1,frm.day.value,frm.hrs.value,frm.min.value); 
var diff = (end - now)/1000; 
var step=(start-frm.v2.value)/diff; 
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=start; 

}
{
myint=setInterval(function(){start=start-step; document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=start.toFixed(2); 
if(start<frm.v2.value){document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Ended";clearInterval(myint)}},1000); 
}

function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myint);
}